# how can I import a text I only get errors

Tags: python, bots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t7I3.png)

wie kann ich nun ein text einfügen der per reddit angezeigt wird anstatt nur der link? weiß das jemand? ich muss einen Feind helfen der promo für seine Musik machen möchte und ich nutz es testweise-

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not in English, and Stack Overflow is an English-only site :)

Comment: Your question should contain a [mcve] with your code as text in the body of the question, and unfortunately needs to be in english

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the `text` parameter incorrectly, if you want to initialize it to a string, use quotes around the string value:

```py
text = "This is the test Text"
```

Without the quotes, python interpreter searches every word for parameter names and keywords, so will result in an error.

Comment: thanks. now I get this error: File "/Users/frederikfrankowski/Desktop/bot.py", line 61
    reddit.subreddit(subreddit).submit(title,url=link,text,send_replies=False)
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument